# Autocompletar input - No devuelve nada la consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Cuando el usuario escribe algo en mi input, quiero mostrar todo lo que coincide de la bbdd para asegurarme que existe. El problema creo que esta en que la consulta a la bbdd no la hace bien y no devuelve nada.
La conexion a la bbdd esta bien, ya lo comprobe.

El codigo PHP:

```
$html = '';
$key = $_POST['key'];

$result = $connexion->query(
    'SELECT * FROM nombres LIKE "%'.strip_tags($key).'%"'
);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    $nombre= $row["nombre"];
    echo $nombre;         
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el **html** que estas usando? ¿por que usas `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Depura tu código. Por ejemplo, puedes imprimir la consulta y probarla directamente en la base de datos. O puedes hacer `var_dump($result);` para verificar si no hay error ejecutando la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Eso quiere decir que hay un error en tu query. La funcion query() devuelve "false" cuando ocurre un error por lo que la variable $result guarda un valor booleano en vez de object.

Creo que la sintaxis de tu query esta mal, para usar operadores como "LIKE" debes tener una clausula WHERE y no veo el nombre de la tabla. Tu query deberia ser algo asi: `'SELECT * FROM nombre_de_la_tabla WHERE nombres LIKE  "%'.strip_tags($key).'%"'`